# javascript - swap dictionary changes type to integer

Tags: javascript, dictionary

So I am using this code for inverting a dictionary - which I found on SO.

```
function g_swap_dictionary ( dict ) {
    let ret = {};
    for(var key in dict){
        ret[dict[key]] = key;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But if I have this dictionary :

```
 [object Object] {
    0: 0,
    1: 2,
    2: 4,
    3: 1,
    4: 3
}
```

and swap it I get this :

```
[object Object] {
    0: "0",
    2: "1",
    4: "2",
    1: "3",
    3: "4"
}
```

so values change to string type. Since I want 'g_swap_dictionary' to be as generic as possible - how can I fix that?

Comment: Object property names always are strings. There is nothing you can be generic about. If you want something else, you should use a `Map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast the value to number with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

```
ret[dict[key]] = +key;
//               ^
```

```js
function g_swap_dictionary (dict) {
    let ret = {};
    for(var key in dict){
        ret[dict[key]] = +key;
    }
    return ret;
}

console.log(g_swap_dictionary({0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 3 }));
```